# How i can Configure Services, Configure like startup.cs in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

now i want to use services.AddSignalR in ConfigureServices and app.useSignalR in Configure using startup.cs.
But my project just have Global.asax, so what can i do now to show this above in global.asax.
I am trying to create real time notification like this video below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bqTmD5Tpjc
But stuck in the first step is configure, any one can help me?
Many thanks

This screen shot from video tutorial
[image: Screen shot tutorial]

Comment: Please provide your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Are you intending to do this in a new project? Why did you create an old ASP.NET app instead of ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @mason Hi Mason, because of we use the old version so now i can't change. Do you have some idea when i can't change my project :(

Comment: The tutorial you're following is for ASP.NET Core SignalR. If you want to add a SignalR server to an old ASP.NET app (non-Core) then you'll need to find an older tutorial specific to the [non-Core SignalR (stometimes called SignalR 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr).

Comment: thanks to all my friend, i will try my best